# Integer being reset within each loop of recursive A* algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, a-star

I've been stuck on this tricky bug for the past few hours, I was wondering if anyone here could help me.

Basically I'm implementing A* through recursion, and I want each node (called a tile in the code) to store an integer value of the number of previous nodes it has passed through. This is so that once the algorithm has found the exit it can work its way back and return the shortest route.

However the turn counter is being reset each time it loops through the function. However if I remove the line:

```
map[y][x].setID(path);
```

It counts up fine, but of course generates a stack overflow error, but I can't really see why this would be causing the problem.

The main bit of code is here:

```
private static Tile[][] findSquares(IntVector v, Tile[][] map, int wall, int empty, int end, int start, int path, int turns)
{
    // System.out.println(turns);
    if (!isHit)
    {
        for (int y = v.y - 1; y <= v.y + 1; y++)
        {
            for (int x = v.x - 1; x <= v.x + 1; x++)
            {
                if (map[y][x].id == end)
                {
                    isHit = true;
                }
                else if (map[y][x].id != wall && map[y][x].id != path && map[y][x].id != end && !isHit && map[y][x].id != start)
                {
                    map[y][x].turns++;
                    System.out.println(map[y][x].turns); //Always Results in 1

                    map[y][x].setID(path);
                    findSquares(new IntVector(x, y), map, wall, empty, end, start, path, turns);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

With tile representing a node. Here is the tile class:

```
static private class Tile
{
    int id;
    int turns = 0;

    Tile(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void addTurn()
    {
        turns++;
    }

    public void setID(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getTurns()
    {
        return turns;
    }

    public Tile setTurns(int turns)
    {
        this.turns = turns;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Perhaps it is to do with the tile class being static?

Comment: where is isHit defined? Also, A* is generally implemented using a priority queue and a heuristic function, but I don't see them.

Comment: You say you implement `A*`, so where is your heuristic function? And which do you use? Note that the `A*` algorithm is just an ordinary implementation of the `Dijkstra` algorithm with the difference of an added **heuristic function** to improve speed. One possible heuristic is *as-the-crows-fly*, but there other possibilities too.

Comment: If it helps, [here](https://github.com/ZabuzaW/PathWeaver/blob/master/src/de/zabuza/pathweaver/network/algorithm/shortestpath/DijkstraShortestPathComputation.java) is a Java implementation of Dijkstra with explanation. And [here](https://github.com/ZabuzaW/PathWeaver/blob/master/src/de/zabuza/pathweaver/network/algorithm/shortestpath/AStarShortestPathComputation.java) is the only change needed to turn it into an `A*`, by using *as-the-crows-fly* from [here](https://github.com/ZabuzaW/PathWeaver/blob/master/src/de/zabuza/pathweaver/network/algorithm/metric/StraightLineRoadTimeMetric.java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't that the turn counter is being "reset", it's that you're never incrementing it more than once. The branch where `turns` is incremented only occurs when `id != path`, but you set `id` to `path` immediately afterward, so it is never incremented again.

What you may have intended is
`map[y][x].turns = map[v.y][v.x].turns + 1;`

At any rate, even if you fix the distance calculation, your code barely resembles A*. It looks like what your code is actually doing is a depth first search with your search stack implicitly maintained on the program call stack.

The A* algorithm involves maintaining a priority queue of nodes to be searched, and uses a heuristic function plus current distance to calculate the new priority of inserted nodes.

Comment: Ah thanks for your help. I think might just scrap it all and attempt it with a better version of A*.